# SSH through Putty comes up with a "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm trying to access out Linux server through Putty but for some reason after a somewhat successful login it just throws a "/bin/bash no such file or directory" then Putty closes.

Contents of bashrc:

```
# /etc/bashrc

# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# By default, we want this to get set.
# Even for non-interactive, non-login shells.
if [ $UID -gt 99 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
    umask 002
else
    umask 022
fi

# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"'
        fi
        ;;
    screen)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
        else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\033\\"'
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
    esac
    # Turn on checkwinsize
    shopt -s checkwinsize
    [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
fi

if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
    # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
    pathmunge () {
        if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
        fi
    }

    # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . $i
            else
                . $i >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset pathmunge
fi
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Non a programming question. Have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/254233/ssh-fails-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Can you access the server locality and show us the content of ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: I have no "bash_profile" file.
I'll post the contents of bashrc

Comment: @Zaforax
I've tried that link you gave me. I cant chroot to the user's home directory. Same " /etc/bash" error.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  to make sure that you don't have a `chroot` directory set. If you do, you will need to either **create** a bin directory in the `chroot` directory and either copy or link the necessary binaries into that directory.

Or you could always comment that line out in the config.

Either way, **restart sshd and test**.

Answer (score 0):

Well `bash` is more than likely located at a different location on this linux box to `/bin/bash`

I've found this to be the case on different boxes and I've changed my `.profile` script in my home directory to not directly execute bash, could be a solution in your case.  So when you log in you stay in the bourne shell, and then go into the bash shell only if you explicitly type `bash`.

Comment: That's the thing, I CANT login :-\
I mean it wont let me. It just throws me out and exits.